# Is this apache vhost config correct?

Tags: apache, http, https, cloudflare, virtualhost

I work with apache for many years and I still don't understand how config works :/

For two websites on same server, having same **one IP address**...

- Can I make it listen to same IP like below ? Because I though it is a must to listen specifying host, e.g `<VirtualHost mybigsite.com:443>` AND `<VirtualHost mysmallsite.com:443>` ?
- With below config, will apache identify the right virtualhost just based on the **ServerName** ?
- With below config, will apache identify the right virtualhost just based on the **ServerAlias** ?

Because I thought the `ServerAlias` is just to know two aliasses are the same server, but I didn't know that multiple vhosts can listen on same IP and differentiate them based on `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, is that how it works ?

Additionally, I am confused about something[else]... can this config cause any response delays ?! Because `mybigsite.com` is actually behind CloudFlare ? This cloudflare setup is also the reason I didn't specify the actual domains by `<VirtualHost mysmallsite.com:443>`. It seems to confuse apache if I define domain name there, because Apache needs to resolve the name to an IP and doesn't like the IP being an external location from this server. If I specify `mybigsite:443` then `apachectl -S` shows the domain as listening on external CloudFlare IPs.

```
# site 1 with many subdomains
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:443> # <<< same ip on both vhosts
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mybigsite.com
        ServerName mybigsite.com
        ServerAlias www.mybigsite.com
        ServerAlias other-subdomain.mybigsite.com

        # certificates here
</VirtualHost>

# site 2, just main domain and www.
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:443> # <<< same ip on both vhosts
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysmallsite.com
        ServerName mysmallsite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysmallsite.com

        # certificates here 
</VirtualHost>
```